# Series convergence and Big O

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove that if there exists $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^{\theta})$, then  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$ converges. Intuitively it makes sense since we have $\frac{f(n)}{n^{\theta}}\leq C$, for large enough n and for some constant $C$, but I didn't have much practice with convergence tests so I don't know what one should use in this case. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(n) = O(n^\theta)$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ then we have for every $s>0$, $\frac{f(n)}{n^{\theta+s}} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. In particular $$\frac{|f(n)|}{n^{\theta+s}} < \frac{C}{n^s}$$ for large enough $n$.

$$\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^{\theta+s}} \right| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|f(n)|}{n^{\theta+s}} \le C' \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{s}}= C' \zeta(s)$$

Hence, the series converges provided that $s > 1$.

Comment: Slight modifications are needed for complex $s$. Taking $Re(s)$ for instance.